# Facebook My Apps: How to set the app permissions

Tags: android, facebook, gideros

I'm developing an app which I added to My Apps on facebook developers. I tested it with my account (which is an administrator account) saving and then reading my game score, which worked just fine.

But then I added another administrator account, the user confirmed, and I tested it again. But now, it says I need an extended permission: publish_actions.

Why does it work for me and not for the second account if we're both administrators?

Can someone please tell me how to set the app permissions on the dashboard? I can't seem to figure it out.

PS: I'm programming with Gideros Game Engine and I want to publish my app for Android.

Comment: Have you approved your app from `facebook` to use that permissions?

Comment: Do I have to do that if I want to test the app with a developer or administrator account?

Comment: I'm not sure about the type of account, but for any app which uses extra permissions (`publish_actions` is included), so you need to submit your app for review first. In the menu (where is your app displayed) the button named "Submit & Review". Check the details about it there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll submit it later... It's still in development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had to add the permissions manually on my apps dashboard. But I managed to add them via code (I'm working with Gideros Game Engine):

```
facebook:setAppId(appId);
facebook:authorize({"publish_actions"})
```

It works for now, at least with administrator accounts, which is what I was trying to do.